# Java Generic functions: Define a set of classes generic object must be

Tags: java, generics, parameters

I'm writing a generic function in java, however, I can't seem to tell if there's any way of setting a list of classes that a Generic Object must be in.

Something like this:

```
public static <T in {String.class, Integer.class, Long.class}> Collection<T> test(Collection<T> val);
```

Comment: That should be a List of instances not classes !

Comment: You could do: `public static <T extends Number> ...`

Comment: @Sam I would normally do the extended class method, however, the classes are generated from XSD's so there's not a way that I know of that I can set some parent class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You can't do that in java.

What you desire is an "OR" bound. Java allows "AND" bounding, eg:

```
List<T extends Runnable & Comparable<T>>
```

But the analogous "OR" is not supported:

```
List<T extends Integer | String> // doesn't compile
```

When you think about it, it doesn't make any sense. Use separate classes/methods for each type bound.

Answer (score 3):

You can have [Bounded Type Parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html) like this for example:

```
public static <T extends String & Runnable> Collection<T> test(Collection<T> val);
```

But your example will not work since you have several classes and Java does not support Multiple inheritance.

Also, your examples `String`, `Integer` and `Long` are `final` so they will not possible to extend anyway.

Comment: I'd be interested to know what class extends `Number` and implements `CharSequence`.

Comment: @PaulBellora Yeah, yeah, I get your point. I didn't realize that he wanted something like the `IN` clause in SQL, I thought he meant that some class had to extend all three classes. I stand corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't do what you're trying to do in Java - if it allowed you to specify a generic from a list, you'd be able to write a function which operated either on Integers or ArrayLists, which makes no sense as they don't share common functionality. If you want to limit your method to certain types, either find a base class/interface which they all inherit from supporting the functionality you need (`public static <T extends BaseClass> Collection<T> test(Collection<T> val);`) or write a set of oveloaded methods, one for each type you want to support.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can and can not at the same time.

In your specific example it is impossible.

But such an example would work:

```
 public <T extends CharSequence & Comparable & Closeable> void go(){
```

For your case I would go with:

```
 public <T extends Number & CharSequence> void go() // same rule applies as extend a class and implement as many interfaces as you want
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that. Generics is only for enforcing type safety (guaranteeing that the type can perform a particular method, etc.). There is no type-safety requirement that correspond to such an "OR" bound. Requirements on type safety only require an "AND" bound.